# Building LESS in Sublime Text 2

Tags: macos, node.js, less, npm

EDITED QUESTION. THIS IS NOW JUST ABOUT BUILDING LESS IN SUBLIME TEXT 2.

I have tried Less-Build and Less2Css. The former says:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'lessc', u'/Users/Alex/Public/CrapMates/Mockups/less/listings.less', u'/Users/Alex/Public/CrapMates/Mockups/css/listings.css', u'--verbose']]
[dir:  /Users/Alex/Public/CrapMates/Mockups/less]
[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

Is it referring to the "cmd" part or the "path"? I have added the LESS command's directory to my $PATH variable after reading some guides.

Less2css alerts me on save saying:

> Could not find lessc.

I guess this is the same issue.

Any help?

Comment: `/usr/bin/less` is a different command. For details, run `man less`. The LESS command is `lessc` and it should be in the `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` directory. I wonder what the output is if you run `which lessc` and `lessc` in the terminal.

Comment: You're right. Lessc is there. Do they both get installed from the same package? Oh I've been an idiot. Less is a UNIX command. Anyway, any ideas why these install to a different directory to Node, contrary to what the website says?

Comment: `/usr/bin/less` is **NOT** installed by running `npm install -g less`. It has been there since you installed your Linux system. It has nothing to do with the CSS pre-processor - LESS. Run `man less` for more information.

Comment: Yes sorry. I edited my comment. I realised this. I have stopped using less2css now, and am just using the less-build but I'm still having issues. Trying to narrow down the cause.